# MongoDB is not producing output with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I am having trouble getting the output of a MongoDB query. When I call the save method:

```
db.users.save({email: "test@gmail.com", password: "test", sex: "male"}, 
        function(err, saved) {
    });
```

The code works, and stores the entry. However, the function (err, saved) isn't called, as far as I know. When I run this code:

```
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var MONGOHQ_URL="mongodb://testUser:testPassword@paulo.mongohq.com:10085/app********";

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    var m = "hello";
    var databaseUrl = MONGOHQ_URL;
    var collections = ["users"];
    var db = mongojs.connect(databaseUrl, collections);

    var d = db.users.find({"sex":"male"}).limit(1);

    response.send(d.email);
});
```

Then I get nothing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you try to add {safe:true} and tell me what happened. I expect that this is a problem: db.users.save({email: "test@gmail.com", password: "test", sex: "male"}, {safe:true}, function(err, saved) {});

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is a common pattern in NodeJS code. `find` is async so the results are not retuned immediately.

Answer (score 1):

var d = db.users.find({"sex":"male"}).limit(1) has no call back function so it goes out of scope and you dont see the response.

Two things first off i would use findOne instead of limit(1) and  secondly you are missing the callback function, try this

```
db.users.findOne({"sex":"male"}, function (err, result) {
  if(err){
   console.log(err);
  }else{

   console.log(result);
   //then do your response here
   response.send(result.email);
  }
 });
```

Hope that makes sense.